# Configuring embedded Derby in Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, derby

Could you please help me set up connection to the embedded Derby database in Spring Boot application?

I searched the web but can only find solutions for server-type Derby, not for embedded Derby.

```
spring.jpa.database = ?
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

Comment: jdbc:derby:memory:demo;create=true

Answer (score 16):

### Derby as an in-memory database

If you want to Configure **in-memory** Derby database with spring boot, the minimal thing you need is to mention the runtime dependency (along with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`) as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This bare minimum configuration should work for any embedded datasource in Spring Boot. But as of current Spring Boot version (**2.0.4.RELEASE**) this lead to an error only for *Derby*

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing
DDL via JDBC Statement
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
```

This happens because of default configuration of`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`  see this spring-boot [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7706) for details.

So you need to override that property in your `application.properties` as

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

### Derby as a persistent database

If you want to use Derby as your persistent database. Add these application properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:mydb;create=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't need connection properties if you are using Spring Boot.  Just add these to your POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then add the usual controller, service, and repository classes.